# Problem with dynamic Tab creation

Tags: asp.net

I create Tabs (almost 18) Dynamically in my ASP.net application and these tabs are taking lot of time to load. I create these tabs during the Page Load event and Tabs mostly contain user controls.

There is no order in which these tabs will be rendered as use has the choice of changing the order. Any ideas/suggestions to improve the performance?

Tab creation is according to the user login. each user had ther on number of tabs. mostly 18 tabs. these tab names, user control names, and itz creating order is geeting from DB.

```
ArrayList tablist = ms.GetMemberScreenTabs(ClientId,UserId);
            Session["TabList"] = tablist;
```

how can i load this as faster as possible.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: My kingdom for edit capabilities...

Comment: @squillman I edited as much as I can, Saved it so that no one else spends time on editing. Going back for the second time to make it look better.

Comment: @joji edited you question to sound better. Please add more info to it may be a sample code.

Comment: just added more informations.

Comment: You will need to add more information like what you load in those user controls etc etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to deal with slow pages that contain tabs.. but in my case it was because the generated page was way too large. The HTML alone was going up to 2mb with the viewstate and all. And then add all the scripts and images etc. The page will seem like it is loading very slow but in reality the server side time was quite nominal.

You should try tracing the page and see how much time it actually takes to render. That would remove the network out of the equation.

Then if needed, you can follow the general page speedup methods like enable gzip, move the viewstate to use session, consolidate scripts/css to single requests, enable caching, lighter images via handlers etc.

Sorry if this seems off topic.